# jquery - passing parameters to functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

This seems like a simple question, but I can't find a simple answer.  So I'll start by giving a simple example.

```
<a href="#" onclick="showmsg('bark')">dog</a>
<a href="#" onclick="showmsg('meow')">cat</a>
```

And here's a javascript function...

```
function showmsg(msg) {
  alert(msg);
}
```

In the above example, additional content (lines of html) may be added without breaking the behavior (the javascript).  Each line of html passes its own parameter to the javascript to tell it what message it should display.

If the html is changed to...

```
<a href="#" class="showmsg">dog</a>
<a href="#" class="showmsg">cat</a>
```

Then how do I write a jquery function that knows which line of html was clicked?  In other words...

How do I pass a parameter to a jquery function?

Comment: Hey Audi, welcome to SO.  I saw your question on my phone, and by the time I got to work to try and answer, it had a wealth of good answers already.  Your question has been edited now, but originally didn't contain preformated code.  I wanted to make sure you knew that you can post code by using the button in the editor that looks like one's and zero's.  That will circumvent any limitations on links or newness of your membership.  Anyway.  Nice to see you here, and good luck!

Answer (score 12):

In this case I'd use a [`data-` attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/), like this:

```
<a href="#" class="showmsg" data-sound="bark">dog</a>
<a href="#" class="showmsg" data-sound="meow">cat</a>
```

And your `click` handler can fetch it, like this:

```
$("a.showmsg").click(function() {
  alert($(this).attr("data-sound"));
});
```

Or in jQuery 1.4.3+

```
$("a.showmsg").click(function() {
  alert($(this).data("sound"));
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/S5E5t/).

*To clarify based on comments:* This is perfectly valid in HTML5, in HTML4 it's not *valid*, but the validator is the only issue you'll have, it'll work in every HTML4 browser.  If it wasn't missing in HTML4, it wouldn't have been added in HTML5...I'd *personally* use it whether it validates or not.

Comment: @darasd - Not, it's not. It's part of the HTML5 specification: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes (and doesn't cause any problems in HTML4, on any browser).

Comment: fair enough, but it is an HTML 5 solution, as it will produce an invalid HTML 4 document.

Comment: @darasd - You're *assuming* the question is restricted to HTML4....why? Given your downvote, please tell me what's incorrect about the answer.

Comment: given that usage of HTML 5 is still pretty rare, I think that it's fair to assume that a non-specific HTML question is applicable to HTML 4. Anyway, SO won't let me undo my downvote until you edit your answer.

Comment: @darasd - I edited to clarify as to alleviate the confusion - but I think HTML5 usage is much more widespread than you think, *especially* for new development, which is a fair portion of SO questions.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is to set a custom attribute that contains the value that needs to be pased to the function. Something like

```
<a href="#" class="showmsg" data-attr="bark">dog</a><br>
<a href="#" class="showmsg" data-attr="meow">cat</a><br>

$("a.showmsg").click(function(){
    var attr = $(this).attr("data-attr");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: you should specify that this is an html 5 solution. it will produce an invalid html 4 document.

Answer (score 3):

The data method is a good way to go. If it were me, though, I'd prefer not to have any HTML4 validation errors by defining the sounds in an object map, then pass the text to that map.  For instance:

```
<a href="#" class="showmsg">dog</a>
<a href="#" class="showmsg">cat</a>
```

```
var sounds = {
    dog: "woof",
    cat: "meow",
    horse: "neigh",
    etc: "etc"
};
$("a.showmsg").click(function() {
    alert(sounds[$(this).text()] || "");
});
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/Q9yWU/**

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correct you can do it like this:

```
<a href="#" class="showmsg" alt="bark">dog</a>
<a href="#" class="showmsg" alt="meow">cat</a>

$(".showmsg").click(function(){
     var msg = $(this).attr("alt");
     alert(msg);
});
```

Comment: If the message need to have space id might not be a good choice. We can choose an attribute like Alt or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly to allow you to show code place the code in your post, select it and press ctrl+k to put in code block.

Back to question in jquery you use:

```
$("a.showmsg").click(function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

You can use "this" to find out what has been clicked

Comment: @ Nick I am aware of this but in his question the changed HTML has no way of passing the variable that holds the sound. So I just displayed text instead for a demo

Comment: In that case I still don't see how it can be used, since it requires the text match the alert...

Answer (score 1):

if you really want to use this HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="showmsg">dog</a>
<a href="#" class="showmsg">cat</a>
```

Just write this:

```
// for dog
$('.showmsg:first-child').click(function() {
  // some crazy code here ..
  return false; // for prevent open href link
});

// for cat
$('.showmsg:last-child').click(function() {
  // some crazy code here ..
  return false; // for prevent open href link
});
```

or

```
$(".showmsg:contains('dog')").click(function() {
  // some crazy code here ..
  return false; // for prevent open href link
});

$(".showmsg:contains('cat')").click(function() {
  // some crazy code here ..
  return false; // for prevent open href link
});
```

and also

```
$("a:contains('dog')").click(function() {
  // some crazy code here ..
  return false; // for prevent open href link
});

$("a:contains('cat')").click(function() {
  // some crazy code here ..
  return false; // for prevent open href link
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With [the on function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (or [the click function](http://api.jquery.com/click/) starting at jQuery 1.4.3), you can pass event data in a really nice way:

```
<button id="clickable0">Clickable 0</button>
<button id="clickable1">Clickable 1</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
  {
     $("#clickable"+i).on('click', {item: i}, function(event){
                        alert("clicked on item "+ event.data.item);
                    });
  }
</script>
```

The main advantage is that the value in event.data.item will be the same as the parameter ("i" in this case) was at the time the onClick was created. This is handy, because in this case, you won't have to worry about the value of i changing while the for loop is running.